# How do you set up TOR in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, tor

I have been looking online and trying to install a VPN or TOR in Ubuntu.  I have the packages for this from Synaptic Package Manager.  I am trying to follow instructions from the Tor site, and have even done the Google thing.

I just can not make it work.  I can make it work in Windows on the same computer using VirtualBox, so my router is not blocking the ports.

Comment: @user5978 Try to rephrase your question so it can be also useful for others

Comment: What do you recommend @Denja?

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider what you are trying to accomplish.

"I'm trying to install VPN or TOR" rings a lot of alarm bells; they are very different things.

TOR provides **anonymity** providing you do not enter peronsally-identifiable information whilst using it. Be aware that the last node on your connection can read all your traffic data, and that anyone can run such nodes!

Propper SSH VPN tunnesl however provide truely **secure** connections (cannot be eavesdropped), although they are not **anonymous**.

---

Guides:

- [Installation of VPN on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VPN)
- [Tor project - Debian/Ubuntu](http://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en)
- [Ubuntu - Tor installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tor)

Comment: Ahhh, I get it now.  So secure is what you want vs just "not knowing who you are".  OK, well I tried itshidden free account but it never stays connected or will hardly ever connect.  What is out there for Linux in a VPN?  I see there are paid services out there but what about free?

Comment: Ah, it sounds like you are trying to browser the internet via the VPN. I am unaware of any free VPN servers that would provide this. You probably want a free proxy server. A google search for "internet proxy" / "proxy server" should find what you're after.

Comment: OK, maybe i should try and explain what I am trying to do.  :)  I have legally bought DVD's that I have placed on my PC for watching.  I have homework for college on my PC.  I go to visit my dad 100 miles away or go on the road with my uncle who is a truck driver and I want to access my computer from anywhere and get to my files, music, and movies.  The other part (which is true) is I want a safer way to download a few TV shows that I like to watch such as Top Gear, Mythbusters, etc.

Comment: @user5978 You should edit your question to include this information that describes what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there anymore help with this out there?  :)

Comment: Your question as it stands is unanswerable. Do you want TOR help? VPN help? Remote access help? Anonymous internet browsing? Media streaming? Remote working? Please pick something and edit your original question clearly :). I've added a new answer that tries to answer what I think your question is based on your comments.

Comment: OK, lets see.  I would like VPN help.  I am not trying to stream my files, just have access to then so I  can download or transfer them to my laptop while I am away....like a file server.  So yes I would like VPN help for security online, and remote access help for when I want to log into my machine when away from home to gain access to my files and transfer them to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to access my computer from anywhere and get to my files, music, and movies. "

You will need a fast upload to be able to stream films to yourself.

There are many questions already on remote access;

- [Setup ubuntu for remote access?](https://superuser.com/questions/158727/setup-ubuntu-for-remote-access)
- [How can I set my computer up for remote SSH access?](https://superuser.com/questions/18612/how-can-i-set-my-computer-up-for-remote-ssh-access)
- https://superuser.com/questions/154812/access-my-home-system-remotely
- [Other results](https://superuser.com/search?q=remote+access+remotely)

This question may also help clarify remote access/vpn confusion;

- [VPN or Remote Access?](https://superuser.com/questions/154009/vpn-or-remote-access)